# URL forwarding to subdomains on the fly (in Rails on Openshift)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openshift

My Rails app creates subdirectories i.e. mainDomain.com/data/usr1 but I need them to be accessible as subdomains like usr1.mainDomain.com. How does one set this up on Openshift to work ever time the app creates a directory? Is it even done in the Rails code?

Thanks for your help

Update: I'm trying to find out if this is something I should do at the Rails level or if it is done that the server "wildcard forwarding DNS" level?

Comment: Could who ever vote down my question explain themselves? (the question seems reasonable)

Comment: What research have you done on subdomains?

Comment: Did you vote down the question? @BobDalgleish

Comment: No. But it's clear that you haven't researched subdomains or understand how they work. It's up to you to research it.

Comment: @BobDalgleish I'm certain Stackoverflow  was designed to ask questions without having to go pull out manuals. Otherwise, why Stackoverflow?

Comment: The word "research" has a number of different meanings. These days, it often means "google it". I'm trying to be very clear here: if you don't know what a subdomain on the internet is, you will never get your question dealt with.

Comment: @BobDalgleish... I know what a subdomain is when setup manually at the DNS level... But I need to know if its something that in the case above is done in Rails?  Anyway, ever hear of the term "there are no wrong questions"? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Update: I'm trying to find out if this is something I should do at the
>   Rails level or if it is done that the server "wildcard forwarding"
>   level?

You are correct. This should best be done using wildcard forwarding.

"Wildcard forwarding" means that **any** request to **any** subdomain will be forwarded to your server. It is up to your program to determine if a subdomain maps to a directory you have created. If you haven't created it yet, you should reject the request.

Comment: Umm, yes, but is it done in Rails? Or is it setup at the DNS level at say CloudFlare?  (with page rules etc?)

Comment: Thanks Bob... Ya see, I knew it had to be a fairly short answer ;-)